# My URL regex isn't perfect, how to fix and make group(s) optional?

Tags: regex

Issue: I need my regex to have an optional group.  Specifically "www" and "(https|http):.

**Regex:**

```
/\A^(https|http):\/\/www\.twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+/
```

**Validation (FYI)**

```
validates :twitter_link, format: { with: /\A^(https|http):\/\/www\.twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+/}
```

I need to make the "www" optional.  Everything else seems to be working good.

**What I need (and in order):**

- Might or might not start with "http:" or "https:".
- Must include: "twitter.com/".
- Must include: Any letter/number/character after "twitter.com/".
- Must include: "status" after the twitter #{twitter_user_name_} like "/gem/status".
- Must include: Only numbers after "status/"

**Such as these possible links:**

**Possible Links:**

```
urls = [
  "https://twitter.com/Twitt_erDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "http://twitter.com/Twit1243terDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "https://www.twitter.com/Twi234_tterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "http://www.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "http://m.twitter.com/Tw11itterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "https://m.twitter.com/Tw11itterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "www.twitter.com/Twitt11erDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "m.twitter.com/Tw11itterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "twitter.com/Twitte345_rDev/status/850006245121695744",
]
```

How to make the "www" and "http/https" optional? And is my regex secure/good?

Comment: I fixed your first rule as you mentioned more than once that "http[s]:" is optional. If you think something is wrong with the edit, please feel free to rollback or edit the question further to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make something optional, you should use the `?` quantifier, which basically means *zero or one times*.<sup>1</sup> Now, if what you want to make optional is more than one character, you simply put it in a group *(preferably, a non-capturing group)* and then follow it with the question-mark-quantifier.

Something like the following should work for all your examples:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+
```

**[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/MDoCM0/2)**.

---

### References:

- [Optional Items](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).
- [What is a non-capturing group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/4934172)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Another optional quantifier is the [`*`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), which means *between zero and unlimitted times* but it's not the right fit for your case.</sub>

Comment: Probably should put a $ at the end since it must end with the numbers as well.

Comment: @Mark Sure, if the URL always ends there. I decided to leave that up to the OP because they might have `/Something` after the numbers.

Comment: Considering that www.m.twitter is not a valid candidate, I would tweak that to `(?:(www|m)\.))?`

Comment: @Mark in order to use the "$" --- how would i tack that on because I would like to use that as the number sequence will be the last group of the url validation.  ive tried a few ways but not working.  I tried just putting d+$/ but that won't work for some reason.  I also realized i need an optional hash "/" for the absolute end of the URL in case someone includes it

Comment: For instance (this works in the website tester) i did: /\A^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+(?:\/\/?)?$\// --- as a validator but it won't work for some reason...

Comment: Just add to the end of @Ahmed's regex: /\A^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+$/

Comment: Looks like the issue was using the $.  I just replaced it with \z --- I guess ruby/rails doesn't like using that as it's apparently a security issue.  That'swhat the error said at least .  thanks tho! everything seems to be working fine!